# Having difficulty installing Audacity 2.1.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, audacity

I'm having a terrible time finding clear instructions on how to install the latest Audacity in Ubuntu 14.04.

[The Wiki](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/CompilingAudacityForBeginners) was not particularly helpful in my case. I'm not exactly a power-user, mind you. So I may have gone astray, here. I was also having a look at some instructions on [another website](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2). I have to admit I'm totally lost.

If someone could post the terminal commands necessary to install all the necessary dependencies, and any other utilities I need to compile and install Audacity, I would be most obliged.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just what problem you have installing?

Comment: I guess I was concerned about having the latest version of the program, and it seems that, had I installed the usual way (through Ubuntu software centre), I would have ended up with a previous version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `audacity 2.1.2` from the PPA [linked on there site](http://audacityteam.org/download/linux/), open a terminal and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

[Here is a link](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity) for the PPA.

Comment: Big thank you, I was getting pretty intimidated by the online documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The cool thing in Linux is that you can install and manage all your software via a package manager in caste of Ubuntu apt

As the latest Audacity isn't in the default repos you have to add a new repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
```

After that it's that easy to install audacity:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

This will automatically install audacity and all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I used these commands, as well as the one to install the repository beforehand posted by Matt

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal from the Dash, Menu, or **Press Ctrl+Alt+T** on keyboard and execute below command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audacity-team/daily
```

This PPA contains daily builds from audacity's git repository at
https://github.com/audacity/audacity

To install run
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audacity-team/daily
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~audacity-team/+archive/ubuntu/daily
Press [**ENTER**] to continue or **ctrl-c to cancel** adding it

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install audacity audacity-dbg
```

[Compilation instructions 5:](https://github.com/audacity/audacity)

First you must download wxWidgets. Audacity 2.1.2 requires wxWidgets 3.0.x, 
preferably 3.0.2, which can be obtained from:

http://www.wxWidgets.org/ .

The libsndfile library is also required and is included in Audacity obtained 
from GitHub.

CMake ( http://www.cmake.org/ ) is required to build the local copy of 
the libsoxr resampling library used by Audacity, unless you install 
libsoxr-dev and use that system library.

Installation of other libraries is optional, see:
   http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Developing_On_Linux#optional .

If you install libraries using a package management system like Apt or RPM,
you need to install the "dev" (development) packages for each library.

To compile on Linux, Mac OS X and other Unix systems, execute these 
commands:

```
 ./configure
 make
 make install  # as root
```

To see compile-time options you can set, you can type

```
 ./configure --help
```

Comment: This PPA is not up to date, it only contains version 2.0.6 not 2.1.2, the 14.04 package is version `2.0.6+git20160129+r3879+31+32~ubuntu14.04.1` it is the same as the version in the repos, you claim "The PPA contains the most recent build of stable release of Audacity (2.1.2 so far)" This is wrong.

Comment: As I have read it has also complete Compilation instructions in the given url https://github.com/audacity/audacity Please see Step 5. Compilation instructions for 2.1.1.

Comment: So, that is not in your answer, you should update to include those build options (including the steps) then your answer will be valid  but without mentioning this and how to do it, this is not much help as the daily build in the repo is an old version.